# Using Jenkins Artifactory Plugin to Publish Build Info But Not Deploy Artifacts

Tags: plugins, jenkins, gradle, build, artifactory

We're looking at using the Jenkins Artifactory plugin with its Gradle Integration, mostly for its License Check feature . In our case we do not need this plugin to publish any artifacts to Artifactory, just the build info and license check info. Is there a way to configure the plugin to do this? No matter what I do, it seems to always run the artifactoryPublish task in Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Artifactory Gradle plugin, set the `publishArtifacts` flag to `false` in the `defaults {}` closure of the DSL.

If you don't use the Artifactory Gradle plugin explicitly, uncheck the "Publish artifacts to Artifactory" flag.